# After changing linestyle in revit api cant find new linestyle in object styles

Tags: categories, new-operator, revit-api, revit, linestyle

I am creating a category in a Revit family that is a linestyle and after i set it, it exists but i just cant find it in the family and yet i f try to recreate it revit creates an error that it already exists. i tried using regeneration and this doesnt work.

ElementId solidLineId = LinePatternElement.GetSolidPatternId();

```
        // The new linestyle will be a subcategory of the Lines category        
        Categories categories = doc.Settings.Categories;
        Category lineCat = categories.get_Item(BuiltInCategory.OST_Lines);

        using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc, "Create LineStyle"))
        {
            t.Start();
            Category newLineStyleCat = categories.NewSubcategory(lineCat, "Black-01-Solid");
            newLineStyleCat.SetLineWeight(1, GraphicsStyleType.Projection);
            newLineStyleCat.LineColor = new Color(28,28, 28);
            newLineStyleCat.SetLinePatternId(solidLineId, GraphicsStyleType.Projection);
            t.Commit();
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how new linestyles can be created

Category cat = famDoc.OwnerFamily.FamilyCategory;
Category newSubCat = null;

```
        if (!cat.SubCategories.Contains(subCatToAdd))
        {
            using (Transaction t = new Transaction(famDoc, "Add new or find existing subcategory"))
            {
                t.Start();
                newSubCat = famDoc.Settings.Categories.NewSubcategory(cat, subCatToAdd);
                GraphicsStyleType gst = GraphicsStyleType.Projection;
                GraphicsStyle gs = newSubCat.GetGraphicsStyle(gst);
                newSubCat.SetLineWeight(lineWeight, gst);
                t.Commit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this an answer? What does it mean? Is the problem solved?

Comment: This is the answer